# Trouble getting mediaelement,js to display youtube video

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

I have tried to use the code in the demo on the mediaelement site to run a youtube video without success!!! However, I have already run both audio and video files quite happily using the siftware, its a great tool!
(copied site: http://mediaelementjs.com/examples/?name=youtube)

I just get a black box that contains a blank control panel at the bottom. Please tell me if I have missed something?

...

`<script src="../java/jquerypack.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="../java/mediaelement-and-player.js"></script>
    <link  href="../css/mediaelementplayer.min.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
    <link  href="../css/mejs-skins.css" rel="Stylesheet" />`

...

`<video id="player1" width="640" height="360" controls="controls" preload="none">

    <source src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt6CUH9bVzI" type="video/youtube" />
    </video>`

...

`<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
       var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1');
    });
    </script>`

Answer (score 6):

It works for me when I tested to make it.

**Edit**

Fiddle missed headers, didnt work with IE.. copy&paste this code and save it as some test.html, open with browser and should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <!-- mediaelement -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.9.2/mediaelement-and-player.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.9.2/mediaelementplayer.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <video width="640" height="360" id="player1" preload="none">
            <source type="video/youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lt6CUH9bVzI" />
        </video>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // declare object for video
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player1');

});
</script>
```

Comment: The CDN URLs in this snippet are broken.  To get it to work, use these URLs: [JS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.9.2/mediaelement-and-player.min.js), [CSS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mediaelement/2.9.2/mediaelementplayer.min.css)

Answer (score 2):

What version of MediaElement.js are you using? I had the same issue while I was using the newer 2.12v.... I then downgraded to 2.9 and everything works correctly again. I realize this question is rather old- probably before the release of 2.12 but if anyone is searching for a solution to this problem currently, I'd recommend downgrading.

http://mediaelementjs.com/js/mejs-2.9.2/mediaelement-and-player.min.js still works